# Maven keeps downloading newer version of dependency

Tags: maven, maven-dependency

I have a library named lib-kafka-wrapper that uses **kafka-clients:2.8.0** dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

mvn dependency:tree shows correctly:

```
[INFO] com.mycronic.as.cdp:lib-kafka-wrapper:jar:0.5.6
[INFO] +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.8.0:compile
```

But if I use lib-kafka-wrapper in another project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycronic.as.cdp</groupId>
        <artifactId>lib-kafka-wrapper</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

it keeps downloading version **kafka-clients:3.0.0**:

```
[INFO] com.mycronic.as.cdp:app-pnp-analytics:jar:1.1.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.mycronic.as.cdp:lib-kafka-wrapper:jar:0.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:3.0.0:compile
```

Edit:

pom.xml start:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Any idea what do I wrong?

Comment: Use `<dependencyManagement>` to set versions of transitive dependencies. Also: `dependency:tree -Dverbose=true`

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev Thanks for dependencyManagement tag, I'll read something about it. But I've thought I do not need to override version number of kafka-clients as it is already defined in lib-kafka-wrapper. I do not know why the newer version is downloaded even if it's not mentioned anywhere else in pom files.

Comment: Do you have Spring Boot `<scope>import</scope>` defined or maybe a `<parent>` where it's defined? Run `mvn help:effective-pom` to find all the actual configuration of the module.

Comment: Please show your full pom file...

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev Actually I use Spring Boot. I've added beginning of pom.xml to the question. mvn help:effective-pom shows occurences with a lot of org.apache.kafka:* libraries version 3.0.0 and also it contains <kafka.version>3.0.0</kafka.version> in <properties>. I assume these dependencies are brought into project by Spring boot.

Comment: @MichalŠpondr, yep - you can override them by overriding the properties or using your own `<dependencyManagement>`

Comment: It seems odd to use `spring-boot-starter-parent` for a project which isn't a spring boot application.